# Permission denied at Customer Subuser API

Tags: python, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v2

I'm trying to manage subuser [account limits](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API/Customer_Subuser_API/account_limits.html) via SendGrid Web API v2, but I keep getting:

```
{u'error': {
    u'message': u'Permission denied, not allowed to manage users',
    u'code': 401
}}
```

What I'm doing is to POST at `https://api.sendgrid.com/apiv2/customer.limit.json` with DATA: `api_user=your_sendgrid_username&api_key=your_sendgrid_password&user=subuser_username&task=retrieve` just like the docs suggest.

```
requests.post('https://api.sendgrid.com/apiv2/customer.limit.json',
    data={'api_user': 'my_sg_username',
          'api_key': 'my_sg_password',
          'user': 'subuser_username',
          'task': 'retrieve'
    }).json()
```

My account has Admin permissions and I am able do changes via the UI, but not with v2 of the API.

Is there any option somewhere which I'm missing?

Few Notes:

- I'm able to create subusers with v3 of the API
- But I'm using v2 here, because there is no `account limits` options in v3.
- I get this error on all `apiv2/customer.*.*` endpoints, thus I cannot follow [this guide](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Basics/API/how_to_create_a_subuser_with_the_api.html)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we cannot answer customer support questions](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745).

Comment: This is a shame, you should probably vote to close all questions with the `sendgrid` tag, because I cannot image how a `sendgrid` related question cannot be categorized as a "customer support question".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am also facing the same problem. I have contacted customer support. They say that there is a v3 endpoint and is not documented. Am waiting for their reply on this. Will update this thread once I get reply from send

Comment: We tried to contact them too, their support is slow, be prepared. I will add updates too, once we have them :)

Comment: We got reply. They are working on adding this to V3 endpoint. They have opened v2 endpoints to us. The reply I got from them:  Thanks for your reply. We have gotten you set up with v2 permissions, so you should be able to hit those subuser endpoints now. In the meantime, we have put in a feature request to allow for credit allocation etc., on the v3 API subuser calls. I have no idea on a timeframe for getting that in place, but It's definitely an important feature for customer's to have access to, in my opinion.

Comment: We finally got a replay, they enable v2 for our account too.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to still be a problem.  V2 endpoints give authentication errors for subuser management.  I was told by SendGrid support to use the following undocumented endpoint, which works for me:

```
PUT https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/subusers/{subUserName}/credits

Body 

{
    "reset_frequency": "monthly",
    "total": 10000,
    "type": "recurring"
}
```

I noticed there is a delay after running this of up to 2-3 mins before it is reflected in the online UI.

Answer (score 0):

In the SendGrid v2 API, all the arguments are form-data arguments, so you need to make sure you're passing them as that, not as part of the body. But it looks like you have that right already.

Beyond that, it's likely something particular to your account, so you'd need to reach out to SendGrid Support directly, and give them your account username.